# Gson dynamic class type

Tags: java, json, class, gson

I am trying to deserialize `JSON` objects in my Java application using `gson`
.

However, I cant figure how to dynamically apply the class type.

I have the class-name in a `String`

```
User user = gson.fromJson(userJSON, User.class);
```

How can I put `String myClass` as class type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is suggested in the previous answer is perfectly OK. Just to avoid all confusions and make it much obvious, here is the full code:

```
package com.test;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

public class TestGSON {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try{
            Object fromJson = gson.fromJson("{\"name\":\"Dharam\"}", Class.forName("com.test.MyClass"));
            if(fromJson instanceof MyClass){
                System.out.println(fromJson);
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyClass [name=" + name + "]";
}

}
```

Output from the above code:

`MyClass [name=Dharam]`

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
```

But your className should be fully-qualified - i.e. com.mycompany.MyClass

Comment: That is given me this error: http://s28.postimg.org/91bjw53wd/Sk_rmbillede_2014_02_13_kl_18_24_17.png